# Using inline css to create 3 responsive columns that collapse to one on smaller device

Tags: css, responsive-design, multiple-columns

I'm sure this is very easy to do and I've just been trying to figure it out too long but here goes. I'm trying to create three columns that will collapse into one vertical column with the order of image, heading, text, image, heading, text, etc. if there isn't enough room for all three. The columns have an image, a title and some text below that. I want the width of the text area to always mirror the image width.

Comment: And where is your code, examples, etc.?

Comment: post some code that you've managed to write but are stuck at.